# Why will vlookup not work when it is the second argument in a nested if statement?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use a nested if statment to pull information from another sheet in excel.
example: if value in column A(sheet1) is located in column A(sheet2) then vlookup corresponding value in Column B(sheet 2) into Column C(sheet1); if not, then if value in column B(sheet1) is located in column A(sheet2) vlookup corresponding value in column B(sheet2) into Column C(sheet1); otherwise "N/A".

the issue is that the values are correctly pulling if the value is in Column A, but not if the correct value is in column B.

example: if Column A(sheet1) is in Column A(sheet 2) the info from Column B(sheet2) will be pulled into Column C(sheet 1), but if this is not the case and the value in Column B(sheet1) is in column A(sheet2), Column C(sheet1) will produce an error code(#N/A).

sorry this is a lot.

I have tried using INDEX/MATCH rather than Vlookup and it still will not pull.
I have checked to make sure formatting is correct and consistent.

```
=IF(A1=(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!A:A,1,FALSE)),VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE),IF(B1=(VLOOKUP(B1,'Sheet2'!A:A,1,FALSE)),VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!B1,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE),"N/A"))
```

I expect this to pull info from Column B(sheet2) if either Column on sheet 1 has a same value as column A on sheet 2. but it only does if ColumnA from sheet one has a same value. otherwise i am given error "#N/A"

Comment: should this "VLOOKUP(B1,'Sheet2'!A:A,1,FALSE)" be "VLOOKUP(B1,'Sheet2'!B:B,1,FALSE)" ? and this "VLOOKUP('Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE)" be "VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B1,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE)"?

Comment: the first one is correct(i believe) "VLOOKUP(B1, 'Sheet2'!A:A,1,FALSE)" because i am checking to see if the value in B1 of sheet1 is in column A of sheet2.
but you are correct about the second one that is my mistake. it should be "VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!B1,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,FALSE)".

Comment: "you believe.."... if you don't know, who does?

Comment: as in, i believe that is how you can check for a value on another page using Vlookup on a single column. if i am incorrect, please let me know.